# WordPress Query data showing

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-shortcode

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbyAg.png)
How I can show the data, according to semesters Like:

**Semester 1**
Data

**Semester 2**
Data

**Semester 3**
Data

**Semester 4**
Data

**Semester 5**
Data

**Semester 6**
Data

**Semester 7**
Data

soo on.

I have tried multiple ways to get data.
Any help will highly appreciated.